# Python TCP socket send String

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

When sending `get` in putty the server response with `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`
**this is perfectly fine** as i am only checking if the server is up and running.

Now i am trying to automate the process in python, but `s.send("get".encode())` **seems to do nothing**, how do I use `s.send()`?

the `s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")` works fine tho

I am also using the same program to check other ports as well.

```
import socket

host = "webmail"
port = 80

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

s.send("get".encode())
print(s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: what does "sending get in putty" mean?

Comment: basically I am establishing a TCP connection via a third party program called putty
to manually send / receive strings (in console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**President James K. Polk:**

> @0brine: This answer shows a minimal correct string to send, however, each "newline" needs to be a carriage-return linefeed pair, e.g. b'\r\n'. Thus s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: */*\r\n') should suffice. –

Answer (score 1):

When you send requests via `socket` you need to ensure to carefully follow the protocol in which the server is expecting. It seems that in this case the server expects valid [`HTTP/1.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) messages, and so you must strictly follow the protocol. In this case, a simple `GET` call would need to look something like so:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
Accept: */*
```

However, note that each line must be escaped properly with what is defined in [RFC7230, section 3, Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) as `CRLF`, which is simply `\r\n`, and one extra one at the end of your message. Therefore, the above message would actually look like so:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n
```

If you are wanting to send raw messages like the above, I recommend checking out two possible modules that can make your life a little bit easier:

- [httpsuite](https://github.com/synchronizing/httpsuite): (disclaimer: I am the author) allows easy manipulation of `HTTP/1.1` requests for `socket` purposes.
- [h11](https://github.com/python-hyper/h11): Similar to the above, but I have personally not used it (found it after writing my module above).

---

You can make your life a little bit easier by abstracting away from `socket`, and instead using something like [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which will allow you to more easily send a `GET` requests:

```py
import requests

requests.get("http://example.com")
```

If you are interacting with different protocols (like `SFTP`, `SSH`, etc.) I would recommend finding modules that abstract away from the raw socket requests, and use them in conjunction. Messing with raw HTTP requests (and/or other protocol) requires a certain level of "confidence" in regards to how the server is bound to reply, and usually these modules will abstract a lot of the backend heavy work (e.g. in the case of `HTTP/1.1` [200-299 and 300-399](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) response codes).

Comment: no, i want to use a TCP connection because i also want to check other services like, smtp, imap, pop, ssh, ...

Comment: @0brine: This answer shows a minimal correct string to send, however, each "newline" needs to be a carriage-return linefeed pair, e.g. b'\r\n'. Thus `s.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: */*\r\n')` should suffice.

Comment: Many http servers will accept invalid HTTP, so for example something as simple as `s.send(b'GET\r\n')` may work.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You are completely right. I originally wrote the answer with the intention to redirect OP towards abstracting out of sockets - not very good in my part. I've expanded my answer to include the `CRLF`. A quick note on your response, your request is missing the ending `CRLF` that most server would require to conclude the message is valid - minor, I know, but worth noting in case OP has some fickly servers never responding.